# How do I get the value from an anonymous expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, anonymous-function

For sake of simplicity, imagine the following code:

I want to create a Foo:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And pass it to a special Html Helper method:

```
Html.SomeFunction(f => f.Bar);
```

Which is defined as:

```
public string SomeFunction<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
```

I want to get the value of Bar inside of this function, but have absolutely no idea how to get it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Simply compile the expression and get the value.

```
Func<TModel, TValue> method = expression.Compile();

TValue value = method(html.ViewData.Model);
// might be a slightly different property, but you can get the ViewModel 
// from the HtmlHelper object.
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error with your code:  Error 14 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It should be `html.ViewData.Model`. My initial post was simply in haste with the property name.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to call `Compile()` on the expression to get the Func and then execute that.

```
public string SomeFunction<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    TValue valueOfBar = expression.Compile()(html.Model); // Assumes Model is accessible from html.

    // Do stuff
}
```

Side note: If there isn't any need for the dynamic expressions or expression analysis you might as well pass the Func directly in instead.

Comment: +1 Reddog also speaks truth here; if there is actually no reason to be examining the expression, then simply passing `Func<TModel, TValue>` is much better.

Comment: Unfortunately the Expression is required for other interactions happening within the method

Answer (score 5):

For those that are using expression without MVT Model, one would obtain name and value of property in a following way.

```
public static string Meth<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    var name = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
    var value = expression.Compile()();
    return string.Format("{0} - {1}", name, value);
}
```

use:

```
Meth(() => YourObject.Property);
```

Answer (score 1):

in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering there is helpfull valuefor method;

public static string ValueFor<TModel, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression);

```
public string SomeFunction<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression){
var valueOfExpression = html.ValueFor(expression); 
//do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Compile()` will use the Roslyn compiler-framework and will emit MSIL-code that will be dynamically loaded into your application. This executable code takes up memory, and in contrast to "normal" memory it is not subject to garbage collection nor can you free it yourself. If you do this too frequently (like regularly during SQL generation) you will run out of memory eventually. I ran into this issue and open-sourced my solutions as an open-source library:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiaPlaza.ExpressionUtils